# IntelliJ IDEA: Can't type { and [

Tags: intellij-idea

So I have a problem where in `IntelliJ IDEA` I can't type In

```
<br>{ --(Alt Gr + B or Ctrl + Alt + B)
```

and

```
[ --(Alt Gr + F or Ctrl + Alt + F)  
<br>
```

I did try to edit shortcuts but there are no shortcuts that match mentiond ones
And when I try using `SquareBrackets` I get a message a little bit like this:  "Cannot perform refactoring. Caret should be positioned at the name of local variable or expression to be refactored"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Replacing the keyboard might help!

Comment: Hi, Prashant.I tried with another one that I have... Same Results

Comment: Well, like it is said - try try try until you succeed

Comment: Just to understand, what keymap are you using? Also, I may be understanding incorrectly: you have problem introducing `{` and `[` in a source code file?

Comment: :) Thank you but I do not think It Is Because that. And Also I just fount IntelliJ staff say this: Please try adding actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true to bin/idea.properties and restart the IDE. But I can't locate idea.properties

Comment: Hi, Federico klez Culloca! 1.I use Default KeyMap. 2.Yes When I try to type The code in IntelliJ. Actually Anywhere In IntelliJ ,In notepad It works (And any othher text/code editor)

Comment: *"1.I use Default KeyMap"* I'm not in front of your machine, so what is the default keymap? I mean, do you normally use Alt Gr + B or Ctrl + Alt + B to type a `{` in other applications?

Comment: Hello, Federico klez Culloca! Oh you didn't mean the IntelliJ's KeyMap? I normally use Alt Gr + B. But It won't work with Ctrl + Alt + B either.

Comment: Doesn't the English UK keyboard (you mention it in the "answer" below) have a dedicated key for `[` and `{` (as Shift + `[`)? Why are you using those other combinations?

Comment: I can answer to that If you tell me do you mean English UK keyboard language or English UK keyboard

Comment: We are speaking about typing, and in the other comment you said *"My Keyboard is on English(UK)"*, so I'm talking about keyboard

Comment: on an unrelated note, add a `@federicoklezculloca` when you answer me, otherwise I won't be notified, and since I'm leaving in a few minutes I may not be able to see you answered when I'll be back at a computer.

Comment: So let me clarify My Keyboard Language is on English(UK)

Comment: @federicoklezculloca Oh sorry, I didn't know that's a thing in StackOwerflow

Comment: So [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg)? Can you see the keys for `[` and `{` on the top right?

Comment: @federicoklezculloca Its [This One](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Croatian_keyboard_layout.jpg). But I use English(UK) Language (I set it in windows keyboard settings) Because It works the same as Croatia Language

Comment: Wait. I just checked my settings I use English(UK) -Croatia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I found a solution to BOTH of the problems So here are the solutions:

This applies for:
KeyBoards Without `[` and `{` keys (I just English-UK ones have those keys)
and IntelliJ IDEA  Deafult KeyMap (May work for some others)

For the "Can't type [ in IntelliJ IDEA":
1.Press `Ctrl + Alt + S` ,`Alt Gr + S` or Goto: File > Settings > KeyMap
2.Extend Folder:`Main Menu`, then folder `Refactor` and THEN folder `Extract`
3.Right-Click onto Field...
4.In the pop-up menu Click on Remove `Ctrl + Alt + F`

For the "Can't type { in IntelliJ IDEA":
1.Press `Ctrl + Alt + S` ,`Alt Gr + S` or Goto: File > Settings > KeyMap
2.Extend Folder:`Main Menu`, then folder `Navigate` and THEN folder `Bookmarks`
3.Right-Click onto Implementation(s)
4.In the pop-up menu Click on Remove `Ctrl + Alt + B`

Hope that helped You :D

Comment: Oh BTW.  FINALLY I CAN USE THOSE CHARACTERS AGAIN!

Answer (score 20):

It worked for me by going to Ctrl+Shift+A (actions) -> Registry... and then disabling "*actionSystem.force.alt.gr*"

Comment: Seems like a new update changed this setting recently. For any keyboard using AltGr key for typing having trouble after updating pycharm, this is the solution.

Comment: For me the value was already disabled, after enabling it, it worked.

Answer (score 10):

Worked for me:
While focus is on PyCharm then <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd> (actions) -> Registry... and then enabling "actionSystem.force.alt.gr"

Answer (score 3):

An other solution (not related to Jetbrain's suite).

This solution suits you if :

- The problem is sporadic (occurring at irregular intervals and eventually disappear)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations seems not works on some other windows app

In this case this is a well known bug in Windows, just close all your **RDP** sessions and the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> will start acts as it should.

Comment: I can't believe it, but this solves my problem on PyCharm 2020.1. I also activated the registry Alt.Gr options (force and fix)

Answer (score 2):

There are related issues on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177327, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975
Problem should be fixed in IDEA 2018.3.
By the way, you could try to add "actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true" option using "Help | Edit Custom Properties"

Comment: the problem was not fixed in 2018.3

Comment: Nor in 2019.1.1 on a fresh windows 10 install.

Answer (score 1):

win10
Pycharm 2018.1.3

1. ctrl+shift+A
2. Registry
3. **ENABLE** "actionSystem.force.alt.gr", which was disabled initially

SOLVED for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by **LaTeX plugin for IntelliJ IDEA**. After its installation the 'Toggle Star' option key was set '*alt+shift+8*' which coincides with **{** of my keyboard. Hence the solution is analogous to your own answer:

1) Open Keymap (double-shift and type keymap)

2) Expand: Main menu > LaTex

3) Right-click 'Toggle Star' and remove the mapping.

4) Apply + Ok

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is happening all over Windows and you have two different active Keyboard Layouts, for example English and German, this is what worked for me (don't ask me why):

switch to english (`win` + `space`), and type a `{` there (`shift` + Key to the right of `P`).

now switch back to your original language and it should be working again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with PyCharm.
Unfortunately none of the mentioned answers worked for me. I am on an MacBook using a German layout keyboard. The Problem for me was a changed default setting in the terminal settings. I had to **disable "Use Option as Meta Key"**.  On a German Keyboard many "special" characters like `[]`,`@`, `{}`, etc. are `alt(option)` Key-Combinations. I think this is true for other european keyboards as well. (I know for the suisse and the danisch for sure)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, another application was using `Alt Gr + 7 && Alt Gr + 8` shortcuts for other processes. So if previous solutions are not helpful, make sure that shortcut is not being used by another program.