# "Alt" key malfunctions on Pycharm

Tags: ide, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

When I switch the typing language to German, the Alt + [right] key combinations don't work at all on Pycharm [Community Edition], but there is no problem using the same combinations with the German language on other IDEs.

For instance, when I want to type a "#" I have to change the language back to English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA: Can't type { and \[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289207/intellij-idea-cant-type-and)

Comment: This is a known bug, It should be fixed in 2019.1.1. (I am currently using #PY-191.6605.3 and the issues are gone).

Comment: Yes, that has been a bug of pycharm previous edition. I upgraded to the new edition and the problem is solved. Thanks for the help.