# Python: Alt Gr key only works in the Python terminal but not in the code itself

Tags: python, keyboard

The Alt Gr key works perfectly fine in the Python terminal (PyCharm), and everywhere else on the pc, such as browser etc. But whenever I try to make any symbols that require the Alt Gr key in the code nothing happens. Nor does the Ctrl + Alt keys work, which should act as the Alt Gr key.

It's impossible to get anything done with this issue, and I'm not too keen on making a new hotkey for the Alt Gr key.

I've tried:

-Pressing Alt + Enter, Alt Gr + Enter and a bunch of other combinations that people suggested on other threads.

-Rebooting the pc.

-Reinstalling Python and PyCharm completely.

The key doesn't work in the Python Console either. It only works in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by following the top answer on this thread: 
[IntelliJ IDEA: Can't type { and [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289207/intellij-idea-cant-type-and)

However, instead of disabling "actionSystem.force.alt.gr" I enabled it.